# Request to move this question to SuperUser | There's a question that's not about gaming. But instead the usage of such software (the Steam platform)

Tags: support, status-declined, migration

Question in question: [Steam opening in another Windows User account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/187948/steam-opening-in-another-windows-user-account/187985)
Request: Can it be moved to SuperUser?

---

Although this question is about the gaming platform Steam, solutions to her problem isn't about gaming-related software; gameplay itself. Instead, it's something that needs knowledge of the Windows OS or the usage of "more complicated software-related stuff" within Steam.

Comment: There's a bit of overlap between some sites. We allow gaming terminology, which would be on-topic on English Language & Usage. We allow story-related questions, some of which would be on topic on Sci Fi & Fantasy etc

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this has to be moved necessarily. While it would be on-topic on SuperUser, as it's a question about computer software, and while there is a good chance that the asker gets competent answers there, it's not necessarily off-topic on this site.

To my understanding, Steam classifies as a game-specific utility and questions about that [are allowed on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), even if the solution can be found outside of it (e.g. in Windows options).

Here are some other questions about technical problems with Steam for reference:

[Steam Installer repair tool](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79687/steam-installer-repair-tool)

["Steam failed to load: *SteamStartEngine(0xbfffdf54) failed with error 1: A Steam Engine Instance already exists"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27332/steam-failed-to-load-steamstartengine0xbfffdf54-failed-with-error-1-a-stea?rq=1)